# Not possible to specify indexes on persistent hazelcast maps

Tags: java, hazelcast

we started using the hazelcast map persistency with our own implementation of `MapStore` recently. With this implementation we store data in a map which has some indexes to speed up queries on the objects stored in it, like explained in the docu:

```
IMap imap = Hazelcast.getMap("employees");
imap.addIndex("age", true);
```

Now the problem is, that by initializing this Map the `MapStore` loader method is called automatically, filling the map with some initial values. After this step, it is impossible to set up indexes, because this seems to be forbidden an a non-empty map. So, we have currently no possibility to use indexes on persistent maps.

Is there any workaround, or is is planned to allow adding indexes on non-empty maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, please see: http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/issues/detail?id=574

Comment: This feature is implemented and will be available by Hazelcast 2.0